# How to pass a value from one JFrame to another (already opened) without creating a new object?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

There are two `JFrame`, one is `Home` while the other is `search`.

`search` finds the item and I need to send it back to `Home` which has called it. Problem is when I pass value to `Home`, it creates a new object every time. But i need to send move between both frame multiple times and keep adding data from `search` and keep adding to a table in `Home`.

```
Home obj=new Home();
obj.sno=val;
```

'new' is opening a fresh instance of `Home` and my previous data is lost.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: without seeing code, one possibility: `home` should have a reference to `search` and call a method of it to *get* the value; another: pass the reference of `home` to `search` so it can call a method of `home` with the value (Summary: values are passed by calling methods, or as return from methods)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good design, but it's a workaround that would help accomplish what you need.

Since search is being called from Home, a possible workaround is passing the home instance to the search constructor.

`Search search = new Search(this);`

And the search constructor would store it as an attribute. This way the search object will have access to the calling home instance. The search constructor would look something like,

```
public Search(Home home) {
    this.caller = home;
}
```

and you might want to have an attribute caller(with datatype Home) in the search class.

When the search is done with it's processing instead creating a new Home object, it can just assign the value to the home attribute. It would look something like,

`caller.sno=val;`

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  **To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.**